# How to parallelize a single quartz job with thread pooling?

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a quartz scheduled job in my Spring boot application to sends items from a **large list** to some webservices trough a method when fired in every 5 minutes.

**I was wondering that my sending process (single send method) can be paralelized?** 
What I want is for example when 10000 items list came from db and threads from thread pool will work simultanously to send all records in that list and job will be finished after all records sent.

**What I've tried** below code, I set a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a 5 threaded pool size. 
And yet when I executed and checked the job logs it says jobs is finished with seconds but it takes a minutes to send all data. It continue working correctly but Job seemed to finished in seconds. It probably says the job is finished after all threads set. This is something I avoid from because needings to know job execution time and logs.

```
@Autowired
MyService myService;

@NonTransactionalService 
public class MySenderService{

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    taskExecutor.initialize();

    public void sendAll(){
        List<Long> largeList = someMethod();
        largeList.stream().forEach(i -> {
            taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myService.send(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So, how can I run this send method with mutliple workers inside a **single** job?
**Or else** is it a good practise to set multiple **identical jobs** for sending same list through same method?

Comment: Your job finsihed (from the perspective of Quartz) however it now runs in the background. You haven't improved anything. Instead divide yuor largeList into x parts (probably 5) and start 5 separate tasks each operating on part of the list.

Comment: Yes, it says job finished when my `sendAll()` method finished. So -just curious- what if I loop over a `while (taskExecutor.getActiveCount() != 0)` before sendAll method is done and when it gets equal I let the method finish? is this still a bad practise? To sum up I wonder the right way to doing this is what you suggested above? Thanks for your answer.  @M.Deinum

Comment: Split your list, use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(<runnable>, taskExecutor)`; This will return a `CompletableFuture`. Collect those in a list. After preparing all the chunks of work, use `CompletableFuture.allOf` to join them. Then on the resulting `CompletableFuture` call `join`, which will wait until all of them are completed. Don't rely on `the active count as Ideally you want to inject the `TaskExecutor` and thre is nothing preventing you from reusing it. If you need more control I would suggest using Spring Batch, which makes this kind of easy to do.

Comment: thanks for helping I 'll try the solution you suggested. I'll keep updated the results. @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Flux, IMHO is the solution that requires less code:

```
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.initialize();

        List<Integer> largeList = someMethod();
        System.out.println(largeList);
        Flux.fromStream(largeList.stream())
                .parallel(5)
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(taskExecutor))
                .subscribe( x -> { System.out.println(x);});

        taskExecutor.shutdown();
```

Don't forget to shutdown the TaskExecutor, but as @M. Deinum said, it would be best to have it created elsewhere and injected in your service.